# How to serve multiple icons at once using express

Tags: node.js, express

I am serving icons from icomoon.io to my webpage using express. I am currently storing each icon to a different route, but can I just serve all the icons at once using the same route? Below is a snippet of my node.js code.

```
app.get('/icons', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/img/SVG/profile-male.svg'));
});

app.get('/icons/search', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/img/SVG/search.svg'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```js
app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'img'))
);
```

Then just link them as:

```html
<img src="/SVG/search.svg" alt="..."/>
```

Comment: Or even use `nginx`